# IDEA not recognizing code changes in Gradle project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a multi-module Java / Gradle project. When working on CLI, the project works just fine. However, IDEA doesn't seem to recognize any code changes. Whenever I write something - anything, doesn't even have to be compilable - to any of the files and press Run, it seemingly "builds" the project and runs it, but no changes are actually made.

Things I've tried so far:

- Invalidate caches and restart
- Delete .idea folder and .iml files
- Cleaning and rebuilding the whole project

Nothing seems to work so far. The only way to get things going is to run `./gradlew clean run` on CLI. I have tried this on both IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio, and both seem to suffer from the same thing. What could cause this?

(Also, I'm not quite sure what to include here - I'm more than happy to provide as needed.)

Comment: Are you using gradlew in the IntelliJ also? Maybe this cause the problem

Comment: In IntelliJ, have you checked that directories for source code (project settings->modules->sources)?

Comment: By way of confirmation - I work with multi-module Gradle projects in IDEA a fair bit, multiple versions of both, and they work together well for me.  But sometimes you need a fair bit of knowledge of how they work to figure out what's going on.  If you're still having trouble with this it might be worth doing up a simple example of your problem https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258849/924597.  If you do decide to go to this much effort: make sure to specify what versions of tools you're using (IDEA community/ultimate edition, Gradle, etc.)